# Postgresql - password authentication failed for user

Tags: python, django, postgresql, authentication, pgadmin-4

Well, I've been working on a project on Django, but a friend of mine was facing a problem so he sent me his project (The entire folder). Anyway, I tried to ***run the server*** but it didn't work. I tried to change the password and the username from the settings file, and when I tried to access the user, the username was changed (as the sql shell recognized it, I think ¯_(ツ)_/¯), but whenever I try to login with the password I wrote in the settings file it produces the following error:

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "Youssef"`

Here's the `DATABASE` part in the settings.py file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'Boards_django',
        'USER': 'Youssef',
        'PASSWORD': '000000',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

BTW, the database is recognized by the PgAdmin4:

[image]

Any idea what should I do???

Side note: I can't access the user, hence I'm not able to use any of the commands of postgresql
Also, when I try to run the server or make anything on the database from VS Code, It raises the following error:

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "Youssef"`

Here's the data in the `pg_hba.conf`

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     scram-sha-256
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

Comment: This question is lacking all the important information: What is in `pg_hba.conf`, what is `password_encryption`, what is the message in the PostgreSQL log.

Comment: Where can I find the ```password_encryption``` ??? and the PostgreSQL log???
Sorry, I'm new to Django 
@LaurenzAlbe

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities:

- you used the wrong password
- there is no SCRAM-SHA-256 password set for the user

  This could be either because no password is set, or because the `password_encryption` parameter is set to `md5`, or because the password has not been changed after `password_encryption` was changed.

  To see the current setting:

  ```
  SHOW password_encryption;
  ```

  To see the password:

  ```
  SELECT rolpassword
  FROM pg_authid
  WHERE rolname = 'Youssef';
  ```

Comment: I have a question, Should I login to his project with my user (change the data from the settings.py file)? can't I just use the configurations of his user on my device??

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about. This is a database problem, so I gave you a database answer...

Answer (score 0):

well, the problem was that my friend had a slight spelling difference in his database, when I added it to my databases in the PgAdmin page, It worked perfectly.

**Thanks to anyone who tried to help**